# Is there a way to hide the browser on-scroll if the body isn't what's scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a page that has a center div that is the keeper of all the content (I need this in order for the page to center and for there to be a top and bottom nav that are persistent), however, what I can't get it to do now is to slide the addressbar away when I scroll down (as it would if the page itself was scrolling) in mobile browsers.  Because what's scrolling is the content of the div, the browser address bar persists.

I'm curious if there's a manual command that I can issue to perform said hide/show of the browser elements when this div scrolls down from its top coordinate.

I'm only concerned in making this work in modern mobile browsers like webkit, safari, firefox, and chrome.

Comment: Can we get a Fiddle with your page's code?

Comment: There's actually quite a bit of code (what with the centered div and the persistent top and bottom nav).  I'm hoping that someone can just point me in the right direction for getting the browser to do what it does when you scroll a normal page (it hides the address bar).  I'll know what to do from there, I just don't know where to look for this feature and the obvious places I've looked don't seem to have it.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is making the addressbar fixed position (not scrolling) when on desktop browser, but static (scrolling) on mobile browser, you can use media queries.

## Example

html

```
<div id="address-bar">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

css

```
#address-bar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

// on lesser width (mobile screen) it will override above rule
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #address-bar{
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you misunderstand me (sorry).  I am referring to the addressbar of the browser itself.  On mobile devices, as soon as you start scrolling on a page, the browser's address bar goes away to make room for more content. If you scroll back up to the top it returns.  But my "page" isn't scrolling, a div on the page is scrolling, which doesn't provoke the browser to remove its address bar element. So, I'm looking for a way to manually remove that element when the div scrolls.